# "POST /" Error (404): "Not found"

Tags: php, html

I'm writing a simple splash page and using node's `http-server` to test it out. When ever I click the "submit button it is suppose to send me an email, instead I get an error on the HTTP server console:

```
[Fri Jul 13 2018 10:02:37 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)] "POST /" Error (404): "Not found"
```

Forgive me if this is simple but I'm not a web developer, here is my code:

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "email@example.com";
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " sent an email" . "\n\n";

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    header('Location: thankyou.html');
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="=content-type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Toby Inc.</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table width="200" border="0">
  <tbody><table Align="center">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"><img src="logoNEW.jpg" width="580" height="710" alt=""/></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- You're probably going to want to play with this
     since the form is aligned to the left side -->

<form action="" method="post">
  Firstname: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
  Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit to be inspired">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The thankyou.html file just says "Thank you"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the config of the `http-server` / how you started it? Did you define routes? It looks like you maybe defined a route `GET /` but not a POST-route. Also, the 404 issue aside, are you expecting a NodeJS server to execute your PHP code?

Comment: @TobiasK well with your last question, when you say it like that, I think I get it

Comment: @TobiasK you are correct

Answer (score 0):

Within the `action` attribute of your form, you should specify the URL of the file it should post the data to.

If you want it to submit to the same page/URL, then remove the attribute entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an SMTP Server installed?

Maybe this one can help you out: 
[enter link description here](https://nodemailer.com/extras/smtp-server/)

already mentioned: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51328072/post-error-404-not-found)